# Escaping double quotes - Prepared Statement in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in JMeter using JDBC Request Sampler. One of the parameters include XML that contains quotes

I am getting the following error:

```
Response message: java.io.IOException: Cannot have quote-char in plain field:[ <xmlns:r="]
```

The setup:

QueryType: `Prepered Update Statement`

SQL Query: `{CALL SPINSERT(?, ?)}`

Parameters Values: `Y, <xmlns:r="">`

Parameters Types: `CHAR, VARCHAR`

I suppose I need to escape the double quotes, any ideas, how this should be done properly?

Comment: How about `&quot;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually as per documentation on JMeter website, but the problem appeared to be that you cannot have a white space after the last double quote.

> The list must be enclosed in double-quotes if any of the values
>   contain a comma or double-quote, and any embedded double-quotes must
>   be doubled-up, for example: `"Dbl-Quote: "" and Comma: ,"`